# MATLAB: How do you apply averaging filter to a square region of a RGB image?

Tags: matlab

I need to get a square region from input, and apply averaging filter to it.
Have tried this, but gives error:

```
I=imread('img1.jpg');
h=fspecial('average');
figure;
h_img = imshow(I);
sq=imrect();
mask = createMask(sq,h_img);
I2 = roifilt2(h,I,mask);
```

The last line gives error.

Comment: I copied the code into Matalb, and it's working. What is the error message?

Comment: Oops. I need this for color RGB image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the problem.
You are probably trying to apply filter to RGB image.

Check the following code sample:

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
h = fspecial('average', 10);
figure;
h_img = imshow(I);
sq=imrect();
mask = createMask(sq,h_img);

if (ndims(I) == 3)
    classI = class(I);

    if (isequal(classI, 'uint8'))
        I = double(I)/255; %Convert I to double before applying filter.
    end

    I2 = zeros(size(I));
    I2(:,:,1) = roifilt2(h,I(:,:,1), mask); %Filter Red plain
    I2(:,:,2) = roifilt2(h,I(:,:,2), mask); %Filter Green plain
    I2(:,:,3) = roifilt2(h,I(:,:,3) ,mask); %Filter Blue plain

    if (isequal(classI, 'uint8'))
        I2 = uint8(round(double(I2)*255)); %Convert I2 to uint8 after applying filter.
    end    
end

figure;imshow(I2);
```

Selecting region:
[image]

Filter result:
[image]